# Output for loop with no whitespace between elements while avoiding CSS

Tags: php, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have the following PHP:

```
<?php
    $items = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux');
?> 

<div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <a><?= $item; ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The raw output is this:

```
<div>
                <a>foo</a>
                <a>bar</a>
                <a>baz</a>
                <a>qux</a>
        </div>
```

It looks ugly and messed up, but that’s the actual output. That doesn’t bother me, though. The problem is that there’s whitespace between the `<a>` tags. In the browser, I get this result:

[image: Elements with spaces between them]

Notice how there’s space between the elements. **I don’t want that.**

---

I know you can use `font-size`, `letter-spacing` and whatnot to avoid this problem, but I don’t want to do that since the problem is in the markup.

I also tried commenting out the whitespace like this:

```
    <div><!--
        <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
         --><a><?= $item; ?></a><!--
        <?php endforeach; ?>
 --></div>
```

Which produced the following output:

```
    <div><!--
                 --><a>foo</a><!--
                 --><a>bar</a><!--
                 --><a>baz</a><!--
                 --><a>qux</a><!--
         --></div>
```

And the following result:

[image: Elements with no space between them]

This is my desired result, yes, but that commenting technique is ludicrous... It also messes up syntax highlighting:

[image: Messed up syntax highlighting]

---

### Question

Is there a legitimate way I can remove whitespace between elements without using CSS or cheesy commenting?

**Edit:** I’m using a simple markup like that just for the simplicity of the question. What would be the best approach to this when I have a lot of elements in the for loop, not just `<a>` tags, where using `echo` would be hard? I.E. where you *need* to close off PHP and use shorthand `<?= ?>` tags?

Comment: Forget this comment

Comment: I disagree with your idea that the problem is with the markup; the problem is with the presentation so css would be the most logical solution to that problem. Using something like `a { display: inline-block; }` would solve your problem.

Comment: I can agree, yes. But I used such simple markup for the simplicity of the question (check my edit). What would I do when I have a more complex structure where using CSS would be tough? I’m looking for some magical PHP function perhaps. Something that simply strips whitespace from the output.

Comment: The more complex the generated html structure, the more sense it makes to solve it with css instead of formatting your source code to match the desired output :-)

Comment: And to be honest, changing the formatting of your code should never change how your code behaves.

Comment: Yep, that’s why I’m asking this question. What’s the right way to do it? And at the same time avoid setting `font-size: 0px` and then resetting it for each and every child element... Which, by the way, would be impossible since many elements rely on the cascaded value of font-size, which is forever lost since their parent set it to `0px`. If I do this, I lose the C in CSS. That doesn’t make much sense either.

Comment: Doesn't `a { display: inline-block; }` work? That would make the most sense as that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and then strip the whitespace with Regex:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<ul>
    <li>foo </li>
    <li>b ar</li>
    <li> b a z </li>
</ul>

<?= preg_replace("/>(\s+)</", '><', ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

The output is captured and then passed to `preg_replace()`. Then, regex matches all occurrences of whitespace *only* between tags, I.E. `>` and `<`. What’s cool is that it won’t remove spaces when there’s text. So the output from above turns into:

```
<ul><li>foo </li><li>b ar</li><li> b a z </li></ul>
```

No whitespace *between* the elements, but the space *inside* them is preserved.

Not sure if it will be a good idea when a lot of content is processed with regex, but still... it seems like a pretty elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of below code to remove space between anchor tag

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item){ ?><a><?= $item; ?></a><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?><a><?= $item; ?></a><?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <?php 
      foreach ($items as $item){
        echo "<a>$item</a>";
     } ?>
</div>
```

**Problem was**  : you said php to output `1 line` and `your text` but php minimized blank spaces including line breaks to single blank space, until it specifically said by `css` or like `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?><a><?= $item; ?></a><?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```